# How do I create a c++ window on a mac?

Tags: c++, opengl, osx-mountain-lion

How do I create a window using C++ on a Mac. Do I have to use openGL?
I am using XCode, if that helps.
I have tried to using the Windows, version but it did not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't really see how this question can be answered in its current form. What do you want to do with this window? Are you making something platform specific? GUI application? Just want to play around rendering some geometry with OpenGL in an empty window?

Comment: It seems like quite a reasonable question to me. It seems that this person simply wants to know how to create a window on macOS. This implies that it's a GUI application. It doesn't matter if they want to use OpenGL or not because making a window is still required in either case.

Comment: It is a reasonable question. Wants to use C++ instead of Objective-C. Many many many people will have this question. The number is growing every year. @Grimmy

Comment: The question makes sense to me. I also want to know how to open a window on Mac using C++. I don't want to use Objectionable-C. I just want a window that I can draw lines, rectangles and text into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I create a window using C++ on a Mac

That depends on the operating system installed ;) I guess you meant to ask *"How do I create a window using C++ on **MacOS X**?"*

> Do I have to use OpenGL?

No. In fact OpenGL is on the opposite end of the equation. Before you can use OpenGL at all you first need a window, created with some other method than OpenGL.

MacOS X makes extensive use of Objective-C and a set of class libraries with a Objective-C API known as *Cocoa*. Creating a window on MacOS X always involves writing some Obj-C code. But, it is perfectly possible to write a wrapper around that to provide a binding toward another language. Obj-C is a rather old language, but recently Apple created Obj-C++, which relates to Obj-C and C++ relates to C, i.e. you can use plain C++ language elements mixed with *Objective* constructs, which makes writing a C++ wrapper even easier.

As for how to do it, and what details matter, this is too complicated to answer on StackOverflow. I suggest you read the source code of some framework library providing portable a window creation API.

Due to their simplicity (not because the create an OpenGL window, that's actually a distraction in this case) I suggest you read into the relevant parts of the source code of [SFML](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/tree/master/src/SFML/Window/OSX) and [GLFW](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/cocoa_window.m)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question, and is even a bit sarcastic. I don't think that it's reasonable for "go look somewhere else" to be considered a reasonable answer.

Comment: @monokrome: The issue here is that there is not "the one true" way to do this on MacOS X. As I explained the whole of MacOS X GUI system makes use of Objective-C, so to create MacOS X UIs with C++ **always** involves some kind of wrapper. And as soon as the question is read as "which C++ UI wrapper should I use on MacOS X" it's immediately off-topic on StackOverflow (primarily opinion based).

Comment: I fully understand the reasoning for this response, but am still not convinced that you ever actually answered the question.

Comment: @monokrome: I don't see how I could give a neutral, but true answer to that anyhow. MacOS is built around the Objective-C object model. Where there certainly is Objective-C++ there is no such thing as a pure C++ window in MacOS. The best you can come up with is wrapper or a framwork library like Qt or wxWidgets. However I don't want to endorse a particular framework as an answer as far as this question is concerned. Sometimes (often?) you've to to live with the fact that certain questions (provably) don't have answers.

Comment: In 2015, probably MacOS. He did say mac. Thanks though for answering instead of piling on to shut the question down.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of libraries available which already handles the platform dependent stuff. For example `wxWidgets` is available on Mac and it can also deal with OpenGL, so you might look into that to get you started. wxWidgets also has a lot of samples, sou you can take a look at it before deciding.

You don't have to use OpenGL, but it is a good interface when you want to draw 2d or 3d images.